# Demo Glassware via screenshare

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

I have built a demo application that I want to demo to a room of people. How do I go about sharing my google glass screen with the audience? I saw that in Google I/O, engineers were using something to share their screen with the audience, how do I get that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [MyGlass](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.glass.companion) Android app has a feature called "screencast" - if, for example, you set up a Nexus 10 with MyGlass, you can then use the mini-HDMI out to project the screencast to a large audience (I'm not sure how you'd hook other Android devices up to a projects, but I know this Nexus 10 method works).

You can find the screencast function at the bottom of the main drop-down menu in the MyGlass home screen.

Answer (score 2):

I would turn debug mode to "on" in my Glass settings and then use [Android Screencast](https://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/) to display the view from Glass on my computer screen. From there I could use a projector or external monitor for demoing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a cool jar that I found called droidAtScreen which uses ADB to render whats showing on the glass onto a GUI; no setup required, easy to use.